# concatenate two objects containing arrays in to one array containing objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to concatenate two arrays that contain objects into one array that contains all objects, i hope it makes sense

```
 getEntries() {
        const linksArr = ['/api/aggregated', '/api/techmetro'];

        axios.all(linksArr.map(l => axios.get(l))).then(axios.spread((...res) => {
            // all requests are now complete
            this.articles = res;
        }));
    },
```

I do get

```
articles:Array[2]
0:Object
config:Object
data:Object
data:Array[10]
    0: Object
    ...
meta:Object
headers:Object
request:XMLHttpRequest
status:200
statusText:"OK"
1:Object
config:Object
data:Object
    data:Array[1]
    0: Object
0:Object
meta:Object
headers:Object
request:XMLHttpRequest
status:200
statusText:"OK"
```

But what i am aming for is:

```
articles:Array[11]
   0: Object
    ...
```

what am i missing? thanks a lot

Comment: well, you are sending your requests as an array so they get resolved correctly, however, the response contains an object with a property called `data` and I guess that is the one you wish to concat, not the responses itself

Comment: yes but either axios.spread((...res.data) nor this.articles = res.data does work

Comment: "*`axios.spread((...res)`*" looks really wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest would be to get the data out of the responses, like

```
... .then( allresponses => 
   allresponses.reduce( (current, item) => current.concat( item.data ), []) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for

```
….then(([aggregateds, techmetros]) => {
    this.articles = aggreateds.concat(techmetros);
});
```

or the equivalent

```
….then(res => {
    this.articles = res[0].concat(res[1]);
});
```

If there can be multiple arrays to concatenate (i.e. `res.length != 2`), you can use `[].concat(...res)`.

Comment: This would still only concat the responses, not the articles under the `data` property

Comment: Thanks a lot Bergi and icepickle, concat always throws `.concat is not a function` ..also if i try to access .data ` .then(res => {
    this.articles = res[0].data.concat(res[1].data);
});`

Comment: @Icepickle Ah, I couldn't decipher that non-JSON representation, I just took the description "*two arrays that contain objects*". Of course it's trivial to add that property accessor, or use `([{data: aggregateds}, {data: techmetros}]) => …` in the destructuring.